# mysql workbench needs serverTimezone

Tags: mysql, url, mysql-workbench

I am just trying to commect locally to a mysql schema, called booksdb, on localhost and the following URL is not working:

jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/booksdb

Specifically I got the following error:
java.sql.SQLException: The server time zone value 'GMT Summer Time' is unrecognized or represents more than one time zone. You must configure either the server or JDBC driver (via the 'serverTimezone' configuration property) to use a more specifc time zone value if you want to utilize time zone support.
at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:129)
at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:97)
at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:89)
at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:63)
at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:73)
...

However, if I use the following one it works:

jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/booksdb?serverTimezone=UTC

I am using mysql workbench on win10. I have to use this trick on every DB I create.. is there a way to fix it?

Comment: workbench is a gui for mysql the rdms, you need the tgmeizoneset because you want to avoid calculating thetome zone, but as you don't know the settings of the server, you need this always, else your program will not cope with the times

Comment: there are lots of tutorials on youtube which shows using workbench without the serverTimezone param so don;t understand

Comment: *...is not working* ? Can you please [edit] your question to tell us more about the failure?

Comment: the tutorials don't consider different timezone, when they explain smething other, so i have in my js scrits als was a compensation for the timezome of the user. tutorials usally don't go deep enough to expalin different this that are more complicated, so i belive that you have date problems and solved it by changeing the tome of that session

Comment: java.sql.SQLException: The server time zone value 'GMT Summer Time' is unrecognized or represents more than one time zone. You must configure either the server or JDBC driver (via the 'serverTimezone' configuration property) to use a more specifc time zone value if you want to utilize time zone support.